# How to save an Access database that has a broken dataset in it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am new to MS Access and have some three linked data tables. Say cars, sites and prices. The cars table has a link to sites and prices, wherein n cars can each have a link to one site and one place. I set "must be filled: false" for both of sitesID and pricesID fields in the cars table but this didn't help it, surprisingly! The issue that hit me while trying to add a car is this one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/you-cannot-add-or-change-a-record-because-a-related-record-is-required-in-table

So I am beginning to understand what went wrong, but I cannot undo my broken dataset, that is, delete it, or edit it, only thing I could be doing is shut down Access through the Windows Task Manager.
Any smart way out of this dead-end street?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to delete the links and start over linking the tables correctly. Use Database Tools -> Relationships to accomplish this. If your database is split, e.g. Front-End/Back-End you'll want to do this in the Back-End where your tables reside. Just Right-Click on the link line and select Delete.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't ask the question correctly and understandably. So, the thing that does not work is about saving the database as a whole. I do not want to split it.

Comment: a0poster, the instructions apply to either single or split databases the only difference is where the changes are made. Since you have a single file just use the Database Tools -> Relationships and delete all relationships then re-establish them correctly.